# Linux: file descriptors from os.pipe() not appearing in /dev/fd

Tags: python, pipe

In the past, I've seen virtual files for all open file descriptors appear in `/dev/fd`. However, currently I'm using Amazon Linux and I am not seeing new file descriptors appear when I run `os.pipe()` in a Python program.

For example:

```
MASTER:hadoop@imrdasem2d14$ ls -l /dev/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 hadoop hadoop 64 Jul 23 15:39 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 hadoop hadoop 64 Jul 23 15:39 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 hadoop hadoop 64 Jul 23 15:39 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 hadoop hadoop 64 Jul 23 15:39 3 -> /proc/30933/fd
MASTER:hadoop@imrdasem2d14$ %
python
>>> import os
>>> a,b = os.pipe()
>>> c,d = os.pipe()
>>>
[2]+  Stopped                 python
MASTER:hadoop@imrdasem2d14$ !ls
ls -l /dev/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 hadoop hadoop 64 Jul 23 15:39 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 hadoop hadoop 64 Jul 23 15:39 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 hadoop hadoop 64 Jul 23 15:39 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 hadoop hadoop 64 Jul 23 15:39 3 -> /proc/31001/fd
MASTER:hadoop@imrdasem2d14$
```

But it's clear that the pipe is working:

```
a,b,c,d
(3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> os.write(b,b"foo")
3
>>> os.read(a,3)
b'foo'
```

So how come my file descriptors for 3, 4, 5 and 6 aren't in /dev/fd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of `/dev/fd` are process-specific. You're looking at the `ls` process's file descriptors, not the Python process's file descriptors.

Have your Python process check the contents:

```
os.listdir('/dev/fd')
```

For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('/dev/fd/')
['0', '1', '2', '3']
>>> a,b = os.pipe()
>>> os.listdir('/dev/fd/')
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>>
```

Comment: Or `ls` the path `/proc/PYTHON_PID_GOES_HERE/fd` to check the file descriptors via `ls`. For example, if Python's `os.getpid()` returns `12345`, `ls -l /proc/12345/fd` would give the listing expected for the Python process.